# Ploty Graph : yAxis values aren't ordered when applying count aggregation

Tags: javascript, angular, plotly

am using plotly Js to my angular project.

when trying to plot a graph normally , everything is going well ( xAxis : numurical values | yAxis: categorical values )

[image]

The main issue here is when applying aggregation on yAxis ( especially 'count' aggregation ) , it works fine , but i got unordered values on yAxis , like it is shown here :

[image]

The code am using , is :

```
this.plotData.forEach(data => {
            const line = {
                x: [],
                y: [],
                type: data ? data.options.plotType.type : 'scatter',
                mode: data.options.plotType.mode,
                stackgroup: data.options.stackgroup,
                fill: data.options.plotType.fill,
                orientation: data.options.plotType.orientation,
                name: (data.options.axes && !this.plotData[0].options.plotType.invertAxes) ? data.options.axes.yAxis : (data.options.axes && this.plotData[0].options.plotType.invertAxes) ? data.options.axes.xAxis : '',
                line: {shape: 'spline'},
                transforms: data.options.transforms && data.options.transforms.length > 0 ? [{
                    type: 'aggregate',
                    groups: [],
                    aggregations: [
                        {
                            target: this.plotData[0].options.plotType.invertAxes ? 'x' : 'y',
                            func: data.options.transforms[0].aggregations[0].func,
                            enabled: true
                        },
                    ]
                }] : []
            };
```